# Showing an error of __init__() missing 6 required positional arguments:

Tags: python, function, class

```
import time
delay = 1.5
class Lawyers:
    
    I set up my constructor with the following code: 
    def __init__(self, someName, someAge, someExperience, someCity, someCollege, someTotalCase):
        self.name = someName
        self.age = someAge
        self.experience = someExperience
        self.city = someCity
        self.college = someCollege
        self.salary = 500
        self.totalcases = someTotalCase
        
     Then added some methods:
    def addLawyer(self):
        name = input("Enter their full name: ")
        age = int(input("Enter their age: "))
        experince = int(input ("Enter the years of experience in the field: "))
        city = input ("Enter which city they are from: ")
        college = input ("Enter the college they attended: ")
        totalcases = int(input("Please enter the total number of cases done: "))
        
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.experience = experince
        self.city = city
        self.college = college
        self.totalcases = totalcases
        #new_info = Lawyers(name, age, experince, city,college)
        print ("Employee added succesfully")
        
    def promotion(self):
         self.salary = self.salary + 200;
         
    def averagecases(self):
        self.averagecasesperyear = int(self.totalcases/self.experience)
        print(self.name, "does", self.averagecasesperyear, "cases every year" )
    

        
    Here I do my main function 
def main():
    lawyer1 = Lawyers("John Smith", 21, 3, "Ohio", "Georgetown", 72)
    lawyer2 = Lawyers("Adam Jones", 24, 2, "Atlanta", "Emory", 60)
    lawyer3 = Lawyers("John Doe", 26, 4, "Seatle", "UCLA", 93)
    lawyer4 = Lawyers("Jessica Adams", 25, 3, "Boston", "Stanford", 83)
    
    listofEmployees = [lawyer1, lawyer2, lawyer3, lawyer4]
    
   
    keeplooping = True
    
    while keeplooping:
        time.sleep(delay) 
        print("Type 1 to see all the available lawyers")
        print("Type 2 to add a new employee")
        print ("Type 3 to promote an employee") 
        print("Type 4 to finish the program")
        
        userChoice = int(input("Please choose one of the options above: "))
        if userChoice == 1:
            for eachEmployee in listofEmployees:
               eachEmployee.averagecases() 
        elif userChoice == 2:
            lawyer5 = Lawyers()
            lawyer5().addLawyer()
            listofEmployees.append(lawyer5)
            for i in listofEmployees:
                print(i.name)
        else:
            break
        
        
main()
```

The code breaks when it comes to lawyer5 = Lawyers()

When it comes to lawyer5 = Lawyers()
it is giving an error of
**init**() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'someName', 'someAge', 'someExperience', 'someCity', 'someCollege', and 'someTotalCase'

I am trying to create a code that will collect the infromation about the new employee(new lawyer) and adds it to the list together with the information of other employees

how can i fix that

Answer (score 1):

You need to init the object with the variables `someName, someAge, someExperience, someCity, someCollege, someTotalCase`

like this

```
lawyers5 = Lawyers("Mac", 12, 1, "Annonay", "Cambridge", 82)
```

if you want to be able to fill these informations later on you need to fill default values:

```
class Lawyers:
    
    def __init__(self, someName="", someAge="", someExperience="", someCity="", someCollege="", someTotalCase=""):
        ...
```

You have another error:
`lawyer5().addLawyer()`

should be:
`lawyer5.addLawyer()`